# Not able to submit file via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Following is my ajax call in which I am sending my form data to a PHP page and diplaying the  messages accordingly. The issue I am facing is with ajax seralize() post my file is not getting posted and send.php gives error in response `Notice: Undefined index: file` . Kindly let me know what is an appropriate way to post form data with ajax `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so files can be send as a post too via ajax.

```
var post_data = $( "#form" ).serialize();

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
           url: "send.php",
            async: false,
            data: post_data,
            success: function(html){

              if (html.indexOf("filerror") != -1)
              {
              alert('error');
              }

              else if(html.indexOf("true") != -1)
              {
                alert('true');
              }
              else if (html.indexOf("false") != -1)
              {
                  alert('false');

              }


            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {



            }
        });
```

Comment: Files aren't serialized, you'll have to use formData for that

Comment: @adeneo thanks, kindly let me know how can i use that for form id `#form`?

Comment: The following answer would help you and give further directions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/2444130

Comment: @akhikhl its says FormData object  is not supported by all/old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`$( "#form" ).serialize()` just get form fields values, not its content(for file). If you want to get file content works with `files` control field:

```
var $fileInput = $('input[type="file"]');
var files = $fileInput.get(0).files;
```

You must work with variable `files` with `FileReader` constructor. But better for file uploading by AJAXuse plugins, for example [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: Check `FileReader` [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) also.

Comment: And if you will use `jQuery File Upload` plugin get the basic example [page](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) source code for implementation it.

Comment: Better will be upload image by ajax via plugin, ajax will return the id of uploaded image. You will append hidden form field with this image id and name `images[]`. After this you can work with form by `serialize` method.

Comment: kindly let me know how to post a file with `id=file` via ajax as per your method? Also will it work in all browsers?

Comment: If you use `jQuery File Upload` plugin, code will work in all browsers (modern and IE 6+). See source of [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) basic example page for more info.

Comment: hey I used `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));` but its not working in internet explorer any idea how to do it for IE

Comment: Also I cannot use any plugin cause I am not uploading file i am send it in an email.